# How can I skip the space if the space came between two characters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have the text:

```
first.getage()  person.getinfo( tow.fff(one) , data ) car.getcompany fff
```

I want to get the output :

```
first.getage()/person.getinfo( tow.fff(one) , data )/car.getcompany/fff
```

my problem when I split by the space I get the output :

```
first.getage(/)/person.getinfo(/tow.fff(one)/data/,/)/car.getcompany/fff
```

that happen because I have space between the ("( )") , so how I can to skip the space if the space came between the arcs ,so the output I want is :

```
first.getage()/person.getinfo( tow.fff(one) , data )/car.getcompany/fff
```

any help ?

Comment: What are you using? regex? split?

Comment: Looks like you don't actually want to split by the space character.

Comment: @tymeJV I think the `**` is OPs failed format.

Comment: @zer00ne I edit the question

Comment: @zer00ne I use split by space but not work in my case because I must to skip  the space if came between arcs

Comment: @kernal The space at the beginning you don't want, just those 2 between?

Comment: @zer00ne yes I want only the space between the arcs

Comment: @kernal regex is the only way I think, and I have a solution but the spaces in front of the string is it unavoidable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138557/discussion-between-kernal-and-zer00ne).

Comment: @kernal Ok, as requested a regex solution.

Comment: You are not showing us what you actually have. You say you have space(s) between the two "arcs" (parentheses) but that's not what you show where you say _"I have the text"_.  I suggest using the "snippet" feature on the question editor toolbar to make something that is runnable in the question to show what you actually have.  Is it `var str = "   first.getage() ..."` or `var str = "first.getage(     ) ..."` Show the results as a vertical (preformatted) list of string elements, not using `/` which makes it look like "/" is part of the output.  We can't answer if the question is inaccurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the result is what is requested, ***but*** remember that it is searching in a different context than looking for arcs. Plus this is contingent upon the condition that the string is trimmed first. Details are commented in Snippet.

**SNIPPET**

```js
// Raw string
var str = ' first.getage()  person.getinfo( tow.fff(one) , data ) car.getcompany ';

// Trim the space off of th start and end of str
var str = str.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '');

/* This says:
|| Find any literal fragment that is ".get"
|| Then find everything that's a character before ".get"...
|| until there's a space.
|| Now replace that particular space with:
|| a space, / , and another space
*/
var rgx = /\s\b(?=\w*(?=\.get))/g;

var res = str.replace(rgx, ' \/ ');

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Read the question again and you'll see the OP asked for fff to be included. So you can't get all based on '.get' string

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira Why don't you read the edits? that fff was added afterwards. Why are you editing the OP's string? Dashes to spaces? That changes the question entirely.

Comment: but anyway, even if it's added afterwards now this answer doesn't make sense don't you think ?

Comment: Why are you editing the OP's string? That's what doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create a regex for this and was unsuccessful. If someone can do a regex it will be much better of course. But anyway if regex can't help us, we get back to the old methods. So here goes in an old-fashioned style:

```js
function mySplitStr(str) {  
  var inFunction = 0;
  str = str.trim().replace(/\s+/g,' ');
  str.split('').forEach((chr, ix)=>{
    chr == '(' || inFunction++;
    chr == ')' || inFunction--; 
    if ((chr == ' ') && (!inFunction))
      str = str.substr(0, ix) + '|' + str.substr(ix + 1);
  });
  return str.split('|');
}

var str = "  first.getage()  person.getinfo( tow.fff(one) , data ) car.getcompany fff " ;
console.log(mySplitStr(str));
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7jazt7y1/7/

Comment: but i want to save the spaces between the arcs

Comment: will try to modify it

Comment: Now it's the way you wanted it to be :)

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira So why are you and the OP constantly editing the string?

Comment: Well now I noticed that. The only thing I did was adding 4 spaces in order to make it's string lines appear as code... investigating how this could have happened.

Comment: Well I tried to figure out what happened but I really don't know. Sorry for any inconvenience. My edit was just to beautify the answer (add 4 spaces), as I commented.

Comment: You added commas.

Comment: I'm seeing that in the edition history, but I didn't to it consciously. As I told you I  don't know what happened. I can't remember nothing I did that could have done that. AFAIR I only added 4 spaces. Anyway... now it's done and the OP already edited my edit, so... what I can say ? sorry.

Comment: I tried to rollback my edition and worsen it. But I re-rolled the last edition from the OP.

Comment: Dude, I already flagged this question and your edit concerning the questionable intent of this post. If you didn't do anything wrong you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138572/discussion-between-nelson-teixeira-and-zer00ne).

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this (+1 to compensate) -- regex & split is not suitable for every job, _especially_ not trying to parse with arbitrary nesting of parentheses.  regex can be used usefully _within_ sub-expressions identified by the parser;  I think Nelson's approach here is much more sensible than OP's attempt at a "split" -- the regex to do that would need horrendously complex look-aheads and look-behinds.

Comment: I guess that's because I accidentally wrong edited the question and somebody thought I did it on purpose, which I didn't. But well, that's people harshness. I'm used to it. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

i can't get rid of the trailing captured group, but i thought it could help !

here's my solution:

```
var str = "  first.getage()  person.getinfo( tow.fff(one) , data ) car.getcompany fff  ";

// trim to remove spaces at the begining and at the end
var output = str.trim().split(/[$\s]+(\w+(?:\.\w+)?(?:\((?:[\s\.\w\(\),]*)\))?)\s*/);

// output = ["first.getage()", "person.getinfo( tow.fff(one) , data )", "car.getcompany", "fff", ""]
```

Comment: In the [$\s] is $ char a typo ? if not could you explain ?